# PHP simple profiler class to find where time used

Tags: php, profiling

I have a problem with my PHP application. Sometimes, i get Fatal error "Maximum execution time of ...  seconds exceeded".

When this error is repeatable i can easy find why a script worked too long and fix . 
But some time an error is not repeatable. I don't have information that helps me to understand why it happened. A code line from error doesn't help (is one of functions called from hundreds of places in the code)

So, i want to add some ways to know where a time is spent if a script works long.

I can not use xdebug or other extensions. Only pure PHP.

My current idea is to set some "control points" in different places in a code and if from one control point to next a time was more then specified time (3 sec or 5, configurable) then do some report to logs

Is there some classes for this? Some good practices or recommendations?